# How to associate filename with user defined functions in makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile which is huge and pretty complex. So I wanted to split that up. While splitting up I have come through an interesting problem.

Suppose I have some user-defined functions in some makefile i.e `tools.mk`, `compile.mk` and `test.mk`

`tools.mk` looks like

```
define clean
    rm -rf some_folder
endef
```

`compile.mk` looks like

```
define generate_binaries
    ...
    creates some executables
    ...
endef
```

`test.mk` looks like

```
define run_test
    /bin/sh runtest.sh
endef
```

Now my `Makefile` takes all these user-defined functions and does some job. It looks like

```
include tools.mk
include compile.mk
include test.mk

.PHONY: build
build:
    $(call clean)
    $(call run_test)
    $(call generate_binaries)
```

Here comes the problem. Now I don't know in which file the clean function is defined. Thus, debugging will be a pain if complexity and scale increase. What I want instead is something like this

```
include tools.mk as tools
include compile.mk as compile
include test.mk as test

.PHONY: build
build:
    $(call tools.clean)
    $(call test.run_test)
    $(call compile.generate_binaries)
```

Could anyone tell me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Make has no notion of namespaces or other forms of source code organization. BUT: sorry if I am asking stupid things, but what do you win with such a scheme? When you think that the location of functions is a problem because there are so many, then I dare to claim that it is the very number itself, which is a problem, not where they are situated. If building software requires so many non-uniform steps then you  should maybe consider programming the build in a general purpose language, because you are trying to run against make's principles and hardly employ its strengths. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: The main problem is I have too many makefiles which are there for different purposes. Now in the main Makefile, I have no way to tell which function is coming from what place as in from which makefile. Thus, I tried a find a way to namespacing them. I considered moving to a scripting language like Python, but that is too much of work

Comment: I think the only way then is to replace the function names with `sed` jobs, but this poses some risk. It is much work, as you already said, and unattractive too.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do anything even remotely like this:

```
include tools.mk as tools
```

But you can run `make -p` and it will show you exactly where all your variables were defined.

Comment: Yeah, I know that this is not a valid notation in Makefile. I just tried to explain what I want to achieve in some kind...

Comment: Understood, and I answered you: you can't do anything remotely like it :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem exists in C as well, where no namespaces exist and modules are imported using `#include`.

The conventional solution in C, and the one I've been using to solve this exact problem in makefiles, is to prefix all names defined within a makefile with a prefix indicating that module name.

Example `test.mk`:

```
define test_run_test
    /bin/sh runtest.sh
endef
```

and corresponding `Makefile`:

```
build:
    $(call tools_clean)
    $(call test_run_test)
    $(call compile_generate_binaries)
```

Once you get used to it, you also come up with names that fit this convention better.